# Limit SQL result in PHP to 5 but only for available entries (there is a table with availability)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the following problem: I select rooms out of a MySQL database. I just want to have 5 on one page, so limit is 5. But I have also an availability table, where blocked rooms are listed. Just available rooms should be shown.

The availability table looks like this. So there could be more than one entry for every room:

```
id room_id datetime_start datetime_end
```

So I did the following to have just 5 AVAILABLE rooms on one page. The Problem: If for example only two rooms are booked in this time, it shows me just 3 results, because availability is checked within the loop.

Thats in short my code. First I get the rooms:

```
"SELECT id, name FROM room WHERE conditions X Y Z LIMIT 5"

while ($stmt -> fetch()) {
...
}
```

In this while loop I have another statement for the availability check:

```
"SELECT id FROM availability WHERE room_id = ? AND ((datetime_start BETWEEN ? and ?) OR (datetime_end BETWEEN ? and ?))"
```

If there is a result, I skip the current while loop with a "continue;"

So again in short the problem: How can I get 5 results on one page even if I skip a few results because of no availability?

Thank you for any hint, I can't find the solution by myself.

Comment: You should combine the two SQL statements (look at JOIN).

Comment: Look at this https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: And note that your test for availability is non-standard, and flawed.

Comment: @Strawberry: Thanks for the update! Could you give me another hint where I find information to make it standard?

Comment: Event A overlaps Event B if Event A starts before Event B ends, and ends after Event B starts.

Comment: @Strawberry: Thank you! But to be honest, I don't really get the point. I am a beginner, sorry. Could you give me further hints?

Comment: Expressed mathematically: a.start < (or <=) b.end and a.end > (or >=) b.start.